# KnockoutJS - Can't map model from pure JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, knockout.js

I'm working on an application that uses a static JSON array that is not provided by any backend service, and trying to bind it to the page with KnockoutJS. I can successfully load the JSON array and even bind the correct number of observables into a ko observableArray, but all of the observables end up being empty. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, as my model seems to be identical to my JSON object setup, and any console logging that I've set up has shown the JSON to be loading correctly. If anyone could find the mistake I'm making, I would greatly appreciate it.

Here's some relevant code, with a jsfiddle to follow:

```
function Item(data) {
    this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    this.category = ko.observable(data.category);
    this.rank = ko.observable(data.rank);
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    this.images = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.price = ko.observable(data.price);
    this.description = ko.observable(data.description);
}

function ChristmasListViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();

    self.selectItem = function(item) {
        self.selectedItem(self.items()[item]);
    }

    $.getJSON("https://rawgit.com/bonso/bonso.github.io/master/scripts/listitems.json", function(data) {
        // var mappedItems = $.map(data, function(item) { return new Item(item) });
        // self.items(mappedItems);
        // console.log(self.items()[0]);
        var tempArray = [];
        $.each(data, function(i) {
            tempArray.push(new Item(data[i]));
        });
        self.items(tempArray);
        console.log(self.items()[0]);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new ChristmasListViewModel());
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8j7g08qr/1/

Comment: In the fiddle I see values are binded properly..

Comment: No, the h2 isn't binding. If you log the first item, you can see it's empty. Or have I really stared at the code that long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot one thing in data-bind.

```
data-bind="text: name" in H2.
```

You can see update in http://jsfiddle.net/8j7g08qr/2/

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much haha. I don't know how I missed this.